# Intellij, local history is not available for one project, not sure why

Tags: intellij-idea

I am used to using local history but for one sub project it is simply not available.

The project uses all static files ( css, js, and such ) but I've also tried to create a maven project to try to make it behave like other projects, but  I still don't see any local history available for files.

I have also tried to recreat the project from existing sources multiple times and it is the same still.

What could be the issue here?

I am on IDEA 14.1.x

Comment: Well if you recreate the project from existing sources, don't you remove the meta data that contains the file history?

Comment: @christopher well, it's easy to recreate some history. But i just realized the problem. The project is part of another project ( which is usually not a problem for local history ) but that other project marks it as excluded ( which it should considering I've got a separate project to edit those files ), however, when it is excluded by a totally separate project, intellij seems to stop managing history for all other projects for those files. I'd say it's a bug.

Comment: You're only meant to exclude non-project files. Why would IntelliJ track the history of non-project items? Sounds like a feature to me but raise and issue with them and see why they think :) Then you can answer this question with the JIRA ticket.

Comment: I am exlcuded a non project directory, but itis a project directory of a separate project.